# WebResponse does not utilize Passed In Cookies for Authentication

Tags: c#, cookies, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am developing a C# console application to extract data from a PHP website.  The website has both a public view and an extended view for logged in users.  I am able to use my credentials, my username and password, to log in to the site via FireFox, Edge, and ID and view the additional material successfully. The parsing of the public data is not a problem, but the issue lies in extraction of the extended data.

I have tried using a variety of methods to create cookies based on my login credentials in order to access the extended view.  My logic behind this is so: there is a login php page with a username and password.  After successfully logging in, each subsequent access to a public page will display additional information (the extended data) if you are logged in.

I am trying to either pass my credentials via as part of the cookie container in the httpwebrequest or copy my existing cookies from firefox (after logging in) to my cookie container for my httpwebrequest.  After that, I would use a HttpWebResponse object to view the returned data stream.  It is there I should be able to identify the extended data in the html.  However, to my knowledge, it has just returned the public view instead.

I am able to open the firefox cookies successfully but I don't know if they are being used successfully in the CookieContainer

```
//!!!!Firefox cookie method!!!!//

CookieContainer ffCookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Cookie ffCookie = new Cookie();
bool fRtn = false;
string strPath, strTemp, strDb, strHost, strField, Value;

strPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\urq2tlhr.default\cookies.sqlite";
strDb = "Data Source=" + strPath;

// Now open the temporary cookie jar and extract Value from the cookie if we find it.
using (SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection())
{
    using (SqliteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT host, name, value, path, expiry, isSecure, isHttpOnly, lastAccessed, id FROM moz_cookies;"; 
        conn.ConnectionString = strDb;
        conn.Open();
        using (SqliteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Value = reader.GetString(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1) + " " + reader.GetString(2) + " " + reader.GetString(3) + " " + reader.GetString(4) + " " + reader.GetString(5) + " " + reader.GetString(6) + " " + reader.GetString(7) + " " + reader.GetString(8);
                if (!Value.Equals(string.Empty))
                {
                    //fRtn = true;
                    //break;
                    try
                    {
                        ffCookie.Discard = false;
                        ffCookie.Expired = false;
                        ffCookie.Domain = reader.GetString(0);
                        ffCookie.Expires = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2025");
                        ffCookie.Domain = reader.GetString(0);
                        ffCookie.HttpOnly = false;
                        ffCookie.Secure = false;
                        ffCookie.Port = "";
                        ffCookie.Name = reader.GetString(1);
                        ffCookie.Path = reader.GetString(3);
                        ffCookie.Value = reader.GetString(2);
                        Console.WriteLine(Value);
                        ffCookieContainer.Add(ffCookie);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("website/view");
request.CookieContainer = ffCookieContainer;

//SECOND METHOD creating cookies based on credentials
string parameters = "username=blah@domain.com&password=blah";
string userName = "blah@domain.com";
string password = "blah";
string url = "example.com/index.php?forcelogin=1";
HttpWebRequest requestTwo = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
requestTwo.Method = "POST";
requestTwo.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
requestTwo.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
requestTwo.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
requestTwo.KeepAlive = true;
requestTwo.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 900");
requestTwo.Referer = "example.com/index.php?forcelogin=1";
requestTwo.ContentLength = parameters.Length;
requestTwo.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
requestTwo.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

using (Stream stream = requestTwo.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] paramAsBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(parameters);
    stream.Write(paramAsBytes, 0, paramAsBytes.Count());
}
CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();

using (HttpWebResponse responseTwo = (HttpWebResponse)requestTwo.GetResponse())
{
    foreach (var cookie in responseTwo.Cookies)
    {
        var properties = cookie.GetType()
                               .GetProperties()
                               .Select(p => new
                               {
                                   Name = p.Name,
                                   Value = p.GetValue(cookie)
                               });

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
        }
    }
    myContainer = requestTwo.CookieContainer;
}
//repeat the cookie reassignment to the web request for the public view of the web page

//READ THE RESPONSE
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;
    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    else
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
    string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    response.Close();
    readStream.Close();
}
```

I expect to be able to see a newly generated html value in the page get response but I don't see it.